# Mysql server can not start as root

Tags: mysql

start mysql server as root failed.

1.service mysqld start

```
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

2.mysqld
error log:

> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.961857Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
>
> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.963350Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.10) starting as process 20924 ...
>
> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.965669Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
>
> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.965715Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.965737Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
>
> 2016-02-23T01:19:16.965818Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

### but can start mysql service as mysql user, or use mysqld_safe as root can start too. what's wrong?

> **/etc/init.d/msyqld start**
>
> > MySQL Daemon failed to start.
> >
> > Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

```
if ! /bin/kill -0 $safe_pid 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "MySQL Daemon failed to start."
    ret=1
    break
fi
... ...
if [ $ret -eq 0 ]; then
    action $"Starting $prog: " /bin/true
    touch $lockfile
else
    action $"Starting $prog: " /bin/false
fi
```

I found this Code Snippets in the script /etc/init.d/mysqld. but don't know why?

Comment: did you just install it ? Also what OS are you running?

Comment: yes, mysql server is installed. the os is CentOS release 6.7

Comment: are you running with local host and is the port you are using free ? is there error code ?  what does ps aux | grep mysql show

Comment: no mysql proccess is running

Comment: use mysqld_safe can start.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysqld start
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/etc/selinux/config

#SELINUX=enforcing
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer a bit (popped up in Review)? Thanks.

Comment: Setting selinux to disabled is significant security implications. If this works, it usually means that you were violating a best practice. Either re-evaluating the configuration is a much safer route forward. It could also very well be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53164165/238322

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `/etc/my.cnf` in [mysqld] section

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

Check this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp)

Comment: after add this have not warnning log, but still can not start mysql server, the same error log

Answer (score 0):

Since you can start as the mysql user, it is likely you have it currently configured to run as root.

[Mysql's reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html) says:

> On Linux, for installations performed using a MySQL repository, RPM packages, or Debian packages, the MySQL server mysqld should be started by the local mysql operating system user. Starting by another operating system user is not supported by the init scripts that are included as part of the installation.